# How to power on ThinkPad T440P from usb keyboard?

Tags: usb, keyboard, power-management, thinkpad

How can a ThinkPad T440P be powered on from a USB keyboard? I haven't found any settings in the BIOS for it.

I have the keyboard, mouse and 27" monitor with displayport. I use it as a desktop and I don't want to open the cover of the laptop, so if the USB keyboard could start up the computer, it would be more convenient.

Comment: Oops.. What a shame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, under Windows 8 & 10, a computer in **Sleep** mode can be wakened using USB keyboard and/or mouse. [Microsoft has published some troubleshooting information if that does not work.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/266283) The most likely issues are that the *Keyboard* item in *Control Panel* is not configured correctly or that the *Sleep* key is configured incorrectly.

[There is a thread on the Lenovo ThinkPad T440 series having issues waking from sleep.](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T/T440s-doesn-t-wake-up-from-sleep/td-p/1403017) The last response I saw is "This is basic laptop functionality that appears to be broken on the new generation of Lenovo Think Pads."

That said, be sure your Lenovo is not entering *Hibernate* mode (or *Hybrid Shutdown* mode) after an extended *Sleep*! Most *Power Plan* settings go to such a complete shutdown to prevent draining the battery. You can extend this time, particularly when on mains power:

[image: Sleep to hibernation setting]

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your solution is to use sleep instead of power off.Use ThinkPad like MacBook  LOL, It's enough for short term  usage,but long term usage, power off perhaps inevitable.Thanks all the same.